# Applying for Canadian visa after US visa refusal & permanent ban

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, visa-bans

I was banned permanently from the US in 2009 for misrepresenting a document issued by an agent that I used. I'm applying for a Canadian student permit and I would like to know if this ban would affect my application?